# Winsock connection test

Tags: c, windows, sockets

How do you test to see if your program is working and able to connect with server? I tried stackoverflow server's ip through port 40 and it fails after a min at `connect()`.

```
test.exe 64.34.119.12 echo 40
```

Program arguments take a syntax: `<Server IP> <Echo Word> [<Echo Port>]`

Also, can you test without having to connect to internet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to connect to your own echo server on 127.0.0.1:7 if it is running, or get a 'connection refused' (ECONN) if it isn't running. Either would show that your code is OK actually.

Answer (score 0):

As for testing without having to connect to the internet...

I'd download netcat for windows.
[NetCat download](http://www.downloadnetcat.com/nc11nt.zip)

Extract the tool, and run:

```
nc.exe -v -l -p [port]
```

If you do that, it opens up a "server" and you can connect to it using your application; just point the IP address to 127.0.0.1!